# Declaring variables with indirect reference with a prefix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, unix

I have my parameters stored in a file and calling them with a prefix which i get it has input. now, i am getting the input and prefixing it and storing as a new variable and then pointing my new variable indirectly to my actual variable to use in my script.

Is there a way to directly mention the indirect variable pointer to my main variable like **value1=$(!$pk_value1)** something like this, so that i can skip the new variable declaration. i have close to 10 variables to be declared which makes my code lengthy.

**My current code :**

```
source values.sh
read -p "Enter Identifier : " pk

value1here=${pk}_value1
value2here=${pk}_value2
value3here=${pk}_value3

value1=${!value1here}
value2=${!value2here}
value3=${!value3here}
```

**values.sh** (I have close to 300 variables declared here)

```
p1_value1=name1
p1_value2=host1
p1_value3=user1

p2_value1=name2
p2_value2=host2
p2_value3=user2
```

Is there a way to directly mention the indirect variable pointer + my name like **value1=$(!$pk_value1)** something like this, so that i can skip the new variable declaration. i have close to 10 variables to be declared which makes my code lengthy.

Comment: How about using an associative array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Bash is recent enough, then use the `-n` indirect variable attribute like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source values.sh
read -r -p 'Enter Identifier : ' pk

declare -n \
  value1="${pk}_value1" \
  value2="${pk}_value2" \
  value3="${pk}_value3"
```

Alternate method with populating an associative array from the file `values.sh`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A values="($(
  xargs -l1 \
    bash -c \
    'IFS="=" read -r k v <<<"$@"; printf "[%q]=%q\n" "$k" "$v"' _ \
    <values.sh
))"

read -r -p 'Enter Identifier : ' pk

declare -- \
  value1="${values[${pk}_value1]}" \
  value2="${values[${pk}_value2]}" \
  value3="${values[${pk}_value3]}"
```

Working of the Associative array population:

`xargs -l1` will translate the `stdio` input stream's lines (here: `<values.sh`) into arguments to a command.

The command called by `xargs` is `bash -c`, witch executes an inline script detailed here:

```sh
# Read variables k and v from the arguments
# streamed as a here-string <<<"",
# using the = sign as the Internal Field Separator.
# Actually splitting key=value into k and v.
IFS="=" read -r k v <<<"$@"

# Format variables k and v into an Associative array
# entry declaration in the form [key]=value,
# with %q adding quotes or escaping if required.
printf "[%q]=%q\n" "$k" "$v"
```

Finally the Associative array declaration and assignment `declare -A values="($(commands))"` gets the entries generated by the `xarg` and inline shell script `commands`.

Comment: Very nice, the text from `man bash` related to creation of a `nameref` is "A variable can be assigned the `nameref` attribute using the `-n` option to ... create a `nameref`, or a reference to another variable." if you wanr to include the reference.

Comment: i used declare -n , but i am getting this error
./tstnew.sh: line 16: declare: -n: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-aAfFgilrtux] [-p] [name[=value] ...]

Comment: @Lea i have tried the alternate method too, only the identifier is getting printed and the values are not getting printed.